# How to store value after running fetch() in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to update state based on the response of fetch() function but i am unable to get the value instead getting Promise {}.If i console.log() the value is correct there.

```
state.product = fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/2")
.then((res) => res.json()
.then((json) => {
        console.log(json); // Correct value
         return json;
       })
     );
     console.log(state.product); // Promise {<pending>}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: No , this does not helped.

Comment: Why not tho? PLease add mmore details

Answer (score 2):

Fetch return a Promise that resolves to a Response object.

Your second `console.log` evaluate to a Promise because at this time the Promise has not resolved yet.

Maybe you can try the following :

```js
async function getProduct(id) {
  return fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => data);
}

const product = await getProduct(2);
console.log(product);
```

Comment: await outside async function is invalid. Have you tried to run?

Comment: By default, Node.js treats JS code as CommonJS modules. Add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file to use ES modules (JS standard). No need with React or Vue as they use Babel under the hood to compile the code.